# Why can't I get the value of a GridView in javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

Right now I am looking for a way to add rows to a gridview dynamically.

And this is what my GridView looks like in HTML:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="Zutaten" HeaderText="Zutaten"/>
            <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="Menge" HeaderText="Menge" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="+" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="Insert(); return false;"/>
```

And this is how I try to insert new rows into the grid using javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">

    function Insert()
    {
        var table = document.getElementById('<%=gridView.ClientID%>');
        //Get values
        var zutat = document.getElementById('<%=tbZutat.ClientID%>'); //this comes from other controls
        var menge = document.getElementById('<%=tbMenge.ClientID%>'); //this comes from other controls
        //Create Cells
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var cell = document.createElement("td");
        var cell2 = document.createElement("td");

        cell.innerHTML = zutat.toString();
        cell2.innerHTML = menge.toString();
        tr.appendChild(cell);
        tr.appendChild(cell2);
        table.firstChild.appendChild(tr);

    }
</script>
```

I do not even know if this works because when I run it I get an exception on the very last line of the js-code:

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property
>   '**firstChild**' of undefined or null reference.

Btw, i am also binding a DataTable to the control in my Page_Load-method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SetInitialRow();
        }
    }

    private void SetInitialRow()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Zutat:", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Menge:", typeof(string)));
        //Store the DataTable in ViewState
        ViewState["ZutatenTable"] = dt;
        gridViewZutaten.DataSource = dt;
        gridViewZutaten.DataBind();
    }
```

So the table variable always is null. Why is that? What did I forget?

Comment: `var table = document.getElementById('#<%=gridView.ClientID%>');` You should pass an id, not a selector. Remove that hash sign.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi sry forgot to remove it before pasting.

Comment: `And this is what my GridView looks like in HTML:` - No it isn't... it's what your GridView looks like in ASP before being rendered into HTML. What is the actual HTML that the browser receives when you run it? Also, is that script inside of your ASP page? What does this part become after being rendered - `document.getElementById('<%=gridView.ClientID%>')`? Does it actually match the ID of the GridView (table)?

Comment: @GuyPassy I had a look at documents innerHTML it appears that my GridView is not existent there. I have no idea why.